# How to email link (URL)

Tags: email, blackberry

I am displaying a page that contains some text and one image. I want to email the URL of this page to some friends. How to do this?

Comment: If not possible...plz give some snipet of mailing consepts in blackberry

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to send the link via email from a Blackberry phone? Or do that programmatically? What have you tried?

Comment: @Curious I want to do progammatically

Comment: I had tried this   http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Send_msg_with_attachment_565471_11.jsp

Comment: Iam getting the error  at Transport trans = Session.getTransport();  " Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getTransport() from the type Session "

Answer (score 1):

Check This -

```
 Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();
 Folder[] folder = store.list(Folder.SENT);
 Folder sent = folder[0];
 Message msg = new Message(sent);
 Address receipent[] = new Address[1];
 try
    {
     receipent[0] = new Address(To_Address, name);
     msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receipent);
     msg.setSubject("Test Mail");
     msg.setContent("This mail is to remind you that programmatically we can send the mail");
     msg.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
     Transport.send(msg);
    }

  catch (Exception e)
         {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: how can we assign To_address,name

Comment: To_address is name@gmail.com  name is "name"

Comment: no need of signin....?can we use this in my app. to send particular iteam through my app

Comment: you have to configure email in your device.

Comment: plz can u guide how to configure email in device?